# Why this for loop in Python3 return dictionary value split in letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

I am lerning Python from a book and there is this example. I rewrote example as it is shown in book, but the result differs from books.

**This is the code**

```
favorite_languages = {
   'jen': ['python','ruby'],
   'bil': 'c',
   'edward': ['ruby','haskell'],
   'phil': 'python',
   'marcis': ['octave','python','mysql'],
   }

for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    print("\n" +name.title()+"'s favorite language(s) are:")
    for language in languages:
        print("\t" + language.title())
```

This is the consoles printed result. Problem as you see are in the way console prints value 'python' for Phil's sentence.

[image: Console spells word Python by letters in each line]

I have tried other IDLE and the same result!
**Why does name python is spelled by letters in each line for Phil's example? Is it an some sort of Python language or my code problem?**

Comment: Your book probably wrote it that way intentionally to make you understand this point precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because line:

```
for language in languages:
```

is iterating over string 'python' and giving you single letters, if you write it as ['python'] it'll iterate over list and write it as one word

Comment: To the OP: The same thing is happening to Bil's favorite language, `c`, but since that is just one letter you do not see it in the printing.